# Collection was modified exception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to query a data table called "Nations" from a `DataContext` object and receive the following exception when calling `SubmitChanges()`:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Below is a snippet of the code:

```
foreach (Nation thisNation in NationList)
{
    Nation nation = nationDB.Nations.Where(c => c.ID == thisNation.ID).First();
    nation.Duplicate(thisNation);
}
```

Where `Duplicate()` is a method that copies some properties of a `Nation` object:

I'm using EF with CTP5.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just by looking at it, this should work, can you expand the code snipped a bit to include the implemenation of `Duplicate()` and `SaveChanges()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though not directly evident here, the problem is usually that you're using `foreach` which can only enumerate the items, and will not allow you to manipulate the collection directly. The approach probably gets a little more temperamental when Linq is involved.

You could replace what you have with a simple `for` loop which should solve the problem - however, this does open up another potential problem should you not address it: you will need to manage the current index which is automatically incremented/decremented by the `for`, lest you'll get 'off-by-x issues'.

Comment: I'm still getting this problem even if I tried to use both yours and AJ approach...

Comment: You say the issue occurs on `SaveChanges` and the snippet here doesn't show us the collection being modified - okay, can we see some more code?

Comment: The Class Nation has fields: int ID, string name, List<Region> regions. The method Duplicate is copying every field one by one.

Comment: I modify the nationDB.Nations collection by copying the values from nationList to the collection. This should be affecting the Database, right?

Comment: Even a simpler syntax, like nation.name = "test" in the foreach loop is throwing the exception when I call SubmitChanges

Comment: I think I solved the problem. Before the code snippet I was executing a number of operations against the nationDB. In one of these operations I was adding to nationDB some of the objects contained in the collection NationList and then calling SaveChanges.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "modified closure" demon.  Try doing this instead:

```
foreach (Nation thisNation in NationList)
{
    var tempNation = thisNation;
    Nation nation = nationDB.Nations.Where(c => c.ID == tempNation.ID).First();
    nation.Duplicate(tempNation);
}
```

Good post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2009/06/25/linq-beware-of-the-access-to-modified-closure-demon.aspx) with more information.

Comment: I don't see how this will have any effect, given that "each closure" is used only once (calling First materializes the query).